# M1 BigSur httpd error LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist

Tags: apache, macos-big-sur

I am a bit confused that Apache `httpd.conf` not in the `/usr/local/etc/` anymore, because there is no visible etc/ folder in the local. It's being empty. So did a bit search and found the a httpd.conf in the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` not very sure it is the right file, because it looks bit different. Anyway the below issue started after loading brew install httpd

> httpd error LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist

when I use the command `brew services start httpd` it gives the message of `==> Successfully started` httpd `(label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)` but when I check the services list I see the httpd error. And when I try to reach localhost I see `It works` message but when I refresh the page no more `It works` message and I only see the **localhost refused to connect.**

what is the correct way to install and run the apache?